# Using abbreviations in 15th Century English

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations

I am writing a story set in the 15th Century. I appreciate that most stories etc were written at the time in either Latin or French but, for obvious reasons, I have to write it in English. It is written in the 1st person and, to make it more personal and immediate, I am considering using abbreviations such as 'I've' and 'I'm'. Would such abbreviations have been used in 15th century English?

Comment: Shakespeare used *I'm*, *I've*, *you're*, *thou'rt*, *he's*, etc. (Although this was 16th century.) But use *'tis*, and not *it's*.

Comment: This might help you: Elizabethan English, also, of course, the Bard. https://www.wappingersschools.org/cms/lib/NY01001463/Centricity/Domain/1504/Elizabethan_language.pdf

Comment: *"I am writing a story set in the 15th Century."* Do not attempt to use 15th century English (late Middle English) unless you are willing to study the subject for 3 or 4 years. You are certain to make many horrible mistakes, and not only in contractions, which are the least of your worries.

Comment: Thank you Peter.  very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

### Subject-verb Contractions

Middle English at the time did have a contraction for "I have" (and [*I* plus other verbs](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED21639)), but it's not the same as "I've": *ichabbe*, *ichave*. These forms reflect the pronunciation of [ich](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/320911/191178), which was the form of *I* inherited from Old English and was undergoing a shift in pronunciation to its modern pronunciation and spelling.

['Tis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%27tis) was apparently in use in the 15th century. ['Twas](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%27twas)came into use in the mid 1500s, a little later.

I don't see any evidence of similar contractions being used with other pronouns during the 15th century.

### Negative Contractions

The only modern negative contraction that I can think of that was in use in the 15th century is *cannot*. From a [c1450 Treatise on Fishing](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/CME00132/1:2.14?rgn=div2;view=fulltext):

> Ye cannot brynge a hoke to a fyche mouthe but yf þer be mete ther-on to hys plesur. (You cannot bring a hook to a fish's mouth unless there is meat on it to its satisfaction.)

There are other words like it (such as *wilnot*) but none of them survived to modern English. Middle English also still had the [negative contractions from Old English](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/430388/191178) (ne + is = nis), though these are even harder for a modern audience to decipher.

As for when people started using modern negative contractions: "The contracted forms [of not] seem to have come into speech ... about the year 1600" — *Negation in English and Other Languages* in [The Contractions of not: A Historical Note](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1015.8872&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (which explains in more detail about how *n't* came to be).

### Other contractions

There are some other contractions that existed at this point, but they're not terribly useful in the modern age.

Comment: THANKS YOU LAUREL.  VERY HELPFUL.